# Eclipse Dark Themes cannot be applied Toolbars

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes

I have started to use the latest versions of Eclipse (i.e. Eclipse SimRel | 2018-09 Edition) and have a look at dark themes available on the web. Although there are some good dark themes available for Eclipse i.e. [Solarized Dark](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=1115), [Tomorrow Night](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=1867), they only changes the code editor, not the toolbars, etc. So, my questions are:

**1)** Is there any dark themes like [Darkest Dark Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle) that updates toolbars and logos besides code editor as well? Or what should be done in order to apply these dark styles to the toolbars (I import themes via *.epf file).

**2)** Do you suggest any other dark themes i.e. *[Solarized by Ethan Schoonover](https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/#usage-development)* on the web? I have searched many pages but most commonly dark themes I like is not available for eclipse as on [What are the best color themes for text editors?](https://www.slant.co/topics/358/~best-color-themes-for-text-editors). Similarly I like the theme of **[Solarized by Ethan Schoonover](https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/#usage-development)**, but there is no Eclipse version.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I advise using the dark theme that is already part of Eclipse. Preferences > General > Appearance. There should be a menu for themes where you can change the theme to Dark. This included theme changes all of Eclipse to a very nice dark theme.